# Concatenate Jobs in Hopac

Tags: f#, hopac

How you would become an `Alt<'a>` out of a `Job<'a>`? Or said others how one becomes one `Alt<'a>` from many, for example from an `Alt<'a>[]`?
There is `Job.conCollect` , which returns `Job<'a>`, but nothing like `Alt.conCollect` which would return `Alt<'a>`

```ml
let deleteById (id: ID): Alt<ID> =
    // ... delete item ...

let deleteItems (ids: ID[]): Alt<ID[]> =
    ids
    |> Array.mapJob deleteById
```

Comment: May be you are looking for `Alt.choose`? Check out https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Docs/Alternatives.md